# how to serialize a form under specific conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Taka a look at this fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fiddlehunt/76ybhnkx/) this is a form where a business user enters the offered services.I sent the data with ajax and by serializing the form.

Click edit and add(plus sign) a service...in the example an input is added where it's name attribute value is of this **form= form[5]...**contrast with this with the form of the name attribute value in the other inputs...only the newly added services have the name attribute like this and the reason for that is to serialize only these...and not the others already present in the DOM/stored in the DB.

And now my problem:
Imagine that the user goes to edit the already registered services(or that he goes to edit them **and** add a new one)...at this case the already registered services wont'be serialized cause of the form the name attribute value has...(and the reason for this is explained above).

What can I do in this case?Sometimes I must serialize only part of a form and sometimes whole of the form.If all the inputs have name attribute value of form[1....] then along with the newly added input...already registered services will be serialized again.
Thanks for listening.

Code follows(you can see it in the fiddle too)

```
    $('.editservices').click(function() {
    //console.log(('.wrapper_servp').length);
    originals_ser_input_lgth = $('.services').length;

    var originals = [];
    $('.show_price')
        // fetch only those sections that have a sub-element with the .value 
      class
        .filter((i, e) => $('.value', e).length === 1)
        // replace content in remaining elements
        .replaceWith(function(i) {
            var value = $('.value', this).data('value');
            var fieldsetCount = $('#serv').length;
            var index = fieldsetCount + i;
            return '<div class="show_price"><p id="show_p_msg">Price 
        visibility</p></div>' + '\
                                    <div class="show_p_inpts">' +
                '<input class="price_show"' + (value == 1 ? "checked" : "") + ' 
         type="radio" name="form[' + index + '][price_show]" value="1">yes' +
                '<input class="price_show"' + (value == 0 ? "checked" : "") + ' 
          type="radio" name="form[' + index + '][price_show]" value="0">no' +
                '</div>'; // HTML to replace the original content with
        });
    $('#buttons').removeClass('prfbuttons');
    $('#saveserv').addClass('hideb');
    $('.actionsserv').removeClass('actionsserv');
    priceavail = $(".price_show:input").serializeArray();

     });
     $('#addser').on('click', function() {

     $('#saveserv').css('border','2px solid none');

    var serviceCount = $('input.services').length + 1;
    var serv_inputs = '<div class="wrapper_servp"><div class="serv_contain">\n\
        <input placeholder="service" class="services text" name="form[' + serviceCount + '][service]" type="text" size="40"> \n\
        <input placeholder="price" class="price text" name="form[' + serviceCount + '][price]" type="text" size="3"></div>';
    var p_show = '<div class="show_p">' +
        '<p id="show_p_msg">Price visibility;</p>' +
        '<span id="err_show_p"></span><br>' +
        '</div>';
    var inputs = '<div class="show_p_inpts">' +
        '<input class="price_show" type="radio" name="form[' + serviceCount + '][price_show]" value="1">yes' +
        '<input class="price_show" type="radio" name="form[' + serviceCount + '][price_show]" value="0">no' +
        '</div></div>';
    $('.wrapper_servp').last().after(serv_inputs + p_show + inputs);
    $('#saveserv').removeClass('hideb');
    $('#remser').css('display', 'inline');

});

$('#cancelserv').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //var newinputs = $('.wrapper_servp').length;
    //var inp_remv = newinputs - originals_ser_input_lgth;
    //$('.wrapper_servp').slice(-inp_remv).remove()

    $('.show_p_inpts')
        .filter((i, e) => $('.price_show:checked', e).length === 1)
        .replaceWith(function(i) {
            var value = $('.price_show:checked').attr('value');
            return '<span data-value="' + value + '" class="value">' + (value == 1 ? "yes" : "no") + '</span>'
        });
});


var groupHasCheckedBox = function() {
        return $(this).find('input').filter(function() {
            return $(this).prop('checked');
        }).length === 0;
    },
    inputHasValue = function(index) {
        return $(this).val() === '';
    };

$('#saveserv').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    //from here
    var $radioGroups = $('.show_p_inpts');

    $('.show_p_inpts').filter(groupHasCheckedBox).closest('div').addClass("error");

    $('.services, .price').filter(inputHasValue).addClass("error");
    //to here

    var $errorInputs = $('input.services').filter((i, e) => !e.value.trim());
    if ($errorInputs.length >= 1) {
        console.log($errorInputs);
        $('#err_message').html('you have to fill in the service'); return;

    }
    if ($('input.price').filter((i, e) => !e.value.trim()).length >= 1) {
        $('#err_message').html('you have to fill in the price'); return;

    }
});
   var IDs=new Array();
 $('body').on('click', '#remser', function(e){


  var inputval=$('.services:visible:last').val();

  if(inputval!=='')
  {r= confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this service?');}
  else
  {

       $('.wrapper_servp:visible:last').remove();

  }



  switch(r)
  {
   case true: 

   IDs.push($('.services:visible:last').data('service'));

   $('.wrapper_servp:visible:last').addClass('btypehide');
   if($('.serv_contain').length==1)$('#remser').css('display','none');
   $('#saveserv').removeClass('hideb').css('border','5px solid red');

              //originals.servrem=true;
   break;



    case false:var i;
    for(i=0;i<originals.ser_input_lgth;i++)
    { 
        $('input[name="service'+i+'"]').val(services[i].value);
         $('input[name="price'+i+'"]').val(prices[i].value);//εδω set value

     }


     $('.services').slice(originals.ser_input_lgth).remove();
     $('.price').slice(originals.ser_input_lgth).remove();

    $('.openservices').addClass('hide').find('.services,.price').prop('readonly', true);
     var text='<p class="show_price">Θες να φαίνεται η τιμή;<span data-value="'+ show_pr_val.value +'" class="value">' +(show_pr_val.value==1 ? 'yes':'no') + '</span></p>';

     $('.show_p_inpts').remove();
     $('.show_price').replaceWith(text);;
          break;

      }

});
```

Comment: I think you should maintain a state of you existing data (loaded at fist time) into some variable, and then compare new data with existing on, other wise if some one just change something in existing one and then again change to original i.e. earlier there was **manikiour** then change to **manikiour1** and then again change to **manikiour** then you must not serialize this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an Idea for you. What you can do is when you show the currently existed value in you html instead of giving name attribute just give data-name attribute. I.e

Change this

```
<input class="services text" data-service="21" size="40" value="hair" type="text" name="service0" readonly="">
```

To This

```
<input class="services text" data-service="21" size="40" value="hair" type="text" data-value="hair" data-name="service0" readonly="">
```

Now when user update this values you can bind an event in jQuery like below.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".services input").on("change paste keyup", function() {
      if($(this).val() === $(this).attr("data-value"))
      {
       $(this).removeAttr("name");
      }else{
       $(this).attr("name",$(this).attr("data-name"));
      } 
    });

});
```

By this way you can give name attribute to only those elements whose values are changed. Now each time you can serialize the whole form and it will only get the value of changed elements.

Don't forget to give unique class to already existed elements so you can bind on change event. Hope its clear to you.

Comment: It will surely work if you will code it correctly. Waiting for your positive response. :) @DimitrisPapageorgiou

Comment: so you are saying that on HTML I should put 2 new data attributes....data-name and data-value

Comment: yes and remove name attribute but keep value attribute. @DimitrisPapageorgiou

Comment: I do not know if you did it on purpose...but the name attribute value must always has this form in order to be serialized:form....(look at the fiddle)...with the value you give it in your code sample it does not get serialized @Smit Raval

Comment: Yes,your solution seems to work very well @Smit Raval

Comment: Glad to help. Happy that it worked for you. :) Also can you please mark it as approved so it can help someone else in future? Thanks @DimitrisPapageorgiou

Comment: There is a slight problem though.Take a look at the fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/fiddlehunt/76ybhnkx/ click edit...you will see a cancel button...with it the user can bring the original values in the inputs in case the user changed them...the code for doing so is in lines 60-64.But in such a case your code does not work....the name attribute is not removed....see for youself.

Comment: it seems there is a problem after all....I must not only send the changed input values to the server but also their respective IDs....serialization alone cannot do that...

Comment: You need to tweak your js code for that @DimitrisPapageorgiou

Comment: there is one little more problem...the user might choose to edit/update also some radio buttons....as I see it these must have name attributes either way...click the edit button in the fiddle to see them.